# Logback file (testlog.log) is not created

Tags: spring-boot, logging, logback

I was using slf4j for logging purposes and everything worked well (file was created on a path I specified and all my logs were there), however, due to my requirements I had to make logger use the JSON format. I decided to use Logback for that purpose but my log file is not created (even tho in the console I see logs written in the JSON format - but for some reason file is not created so I can see those logs only in the console)

Here is my setup:

application.properties

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
logging.file.path=./install/my-project/logs
logging.file.name=${logging.file.path}/testlog.log
```

POM.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback.contrib</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.contrib.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback.contrib</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-json-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.contrib.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
```

logback.xml

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
            <layout class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.json.classic.JsonLayout">
                <timestampFormat>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX</timestampFormat>
                <timestampFormatTimezoneId>Etc/UTC</timestampFormatTimezoneId>

                <jsonFormatter class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.jackson.JacksonJsonFormatter">
                    <prettyPrint>true</prettyPrint>
                </jsonFormatter>
            </layout>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

So with this setup, I see my logs in the console formatted as JSON, however,log file is not created. If I remove these dependencies, and delete logback.xml file and then I restart my application, then my logging works perfectly (log file is created on a specified location) however it's not a JSON format.

I've tried a lot of different options but I cannot figure out why I'm having this strange problem.

Hope you guys can help me

Comment: You only have  <appender-ref ref="stdout"/> you must also create a file appender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *"Simon Martinelli"* pointed out, I had to add file appender as well so my logback.xml file now looks like this:

```
<configuration>

    <property name="HOME_LOG" value="./install/my-project/logs"/>

    <appender name="FILE-ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${HOME_LOG}</file>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>logs/archived/app.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <!-- each archived file, size max 10MB -->
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            <!-- total size of all archive files, if total size > 20GB, it will delete old archived file -->
            <totalSizeCap>20GB</totalSizeCap>
            <!-- 60 days to keep -->
            <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
            <layout class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.json.classic.JsonLayout">
                <timestampFormat>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX</timestampFormat>
                <timestampFormatTimezoneId>Etc/UTC</timestampFormatTimezoneId>

                <jsonFormatter class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.jackson.JacksonJsonFormatter">
                    <prettyPrint>true</prettyPrint>
                </jsonFormatter>
            </layout>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.mkyong" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
    </logger>

    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
    </root>
    
     <appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
            <layout class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.json.classic.JsonLayout">
                <timestampFormat>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX</timestampFormat>
                <timestampFormatTimezoneId>Etc/UTC</timestampFormatTimezoneId>

                <jsonFormatter class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.jackson.JacksonJsonFormatter">
                    <prettyPrint>true</prettyPrint>
                </jsonFormatter>
            </layout>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Thanks!